# Objective C - UIImagePickerController callback

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm implementing the

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

delegate method for UIImagePickerController.

How can I determine in that method if the callback is coming from UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera or UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 2):

Should be pretty simple:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
        // ...
    }
}
```